# Unable to achieve a smooth transition when opening answers in a Styled component

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, styled-components

When I click on a question I want the answer to open (slide to the bottom) smoothly. I searched for solutions but nothing worked so far.
Any help will be appriciated.
First I did a conditional rendering but than I read that I need something to transition from so I added classes.

My component so far after changes:

```
 const StyledQContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
`;

const StyledParagraph = styled.p`
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;

  ${(props) =>
    props.type
      ? css`
          font-weight: 700;
        `
      : css`
          font-weight: 400;
        `}

  &.show {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 6px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 220px;
    color: var(--text-color-grayish-blue);
    height: 50px;
    transition: all 10s ease-in-out;
  }

  &.close {
    height: 0px;
    display: none;
  }

  /* ${(props) =>
    props.type === "par"
      ? css`
          margin-top: 6px;
          font-weight: 400;
          font-size: 11px;
          width: 220px;
          color: var(--text-color-grayish-blue);
          transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
        `
      : css`
          margin-top: 0;
        `} */
`;

const StyledArrow = styled.img`
  width: 9px;
  height: 7px;

  ${(props) =>
    props.type
      ? css`
          rotate: 180deg;
        `
      : css`
          rotate: 0deg;
        `}
`;

const StyledHr = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: var(--divider-color-light-grayish-blue);
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
`;

function Question({ qa, openQ, setOpenQ }) {
  const isClicked = qa.id === openQ;

  function handleClick() {
    if (isClicked) {
      setOpenQ(null);
    } else {
      setOpenQ(qa.id);
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      <StyledQContainer onClick={handleClick}>
        <StyledParagraph type={isClicked}>{qa.q}</StyledParagraph>
        <StyledArrow
          src="icon-arrow-down.svg"
          alt="arrow icon"
          type={isClicked}
        />
      </StyledQContainer>
      {/* {isClicked ? <StyledParagraph type="par">{qa.a}</StyledParagraph> : ""} */}
      <StyledParagraph type="par" className={isClicked ? "show" : "close"}>
        {qa.a}
      </StyledParagraph>
      <StyledHr />
    </>
  );
}
```